# incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS' when I use a nested CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing this sql query but whenever i run it i get incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. Is there something wrong the code?

```
SELECT PA.PolExec, SUM(ISNULL(PR.Re,0) + ISNULL(PF.Re,0)) AS Revenue, 
    CASE P.PolTypeLOB
        WHEN 'Me%' THEN 'MED'
        WHEN 'Pre' THEN 'MED'
        ELSE CASE P.TypeOfBus
            WHEN 1 THEN 'PL'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'CL'
            ELSE 'BEN'
        END AS PolType
    END AS PolType
```

Comment: You cannot assign an alias within a `case` expression.  Remove the first `as PolType`.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Pretty sure that "incorrect syntax near" is SQL server, not MySQL. Please tag your questions accurately

Answer (score 1):

Take out the internal alias -- it does not make sense

So it would look like this:

```
CASE P.PolTypeLOB
    WHEN 'Me%' THEN 'MED'
    WHEN 'Pre' THEN 'MED'
    ELSE CASE P.TypeOfBus
        WHEN 1 THEN 'PL'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'CL'
        ELSE 'BEN'
    END
END AS PolType
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd eliminate the nesting and write it like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN P.PolTypeLOB IN ('Me%', 'Pre') THEN 'MED' 
    WHEN P.TypeOfBus = 1 THEN 'PL'
    WHEN P.TypeOfBus = 2 THEN 'CL' 
    ELSE 'BEN' END AS PolType
```